# Python input method

Tags: python, input, methods, syntax

I tried to execute the following code as stated in a book but the ide shows parenthesis error and syntax error. The code is given below.

```
print "How old are you?",
age = raw_input()
print "How tall are you?",
height = raw_input()
print "How much do you weigh?",
weight = raw_input()
print "So, you're %r old, %r tall and %r heavy." % (
age, height, weight)
```

Comment: Please format your code properly and post the whole error message.

Comment: it is code for Python 2 - if you use Python 3 then you will have to change it. ie. `print(text)` needs `()`. OR better change book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You example is for Python 2, which is the old version of Python. Probably you use version 3. Variant for Python 3 would be:

```py
print("How old are you?", end=' ')
age = input()
print("How tall are you?", end=' ')
height = input()
print("How much do you weigh?", end=' ')
weight = input()
print("So, you're %r old, %r tall and %r heavy." % (age, height, weight))
```